# First service for a 2015 Ford Edge AWD

Tags: ford, service

I have a 2015 Ford Edge AWD that I've had since new. I've had it for 12 months now, and I've done a measly 2,800 miles in it.

One thing I have not done with it is have it serviced. Normally when I've bought cars in the past, they come with a specific book that tells you *exactly* when to get the car serviced (miles/months). This car does not have that, but what it does have is incomplete information in the [user manual](http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/Catalog/owner_information/2015-Edge-Owners-Manual-version-1_om_EN-US_12_2014.pdf):

> When the oil change message appears in
>   the information display, it is time for an oil
>   change.

This is what I've been waiting for - that little wrench to appear on the dashboard. But it's never arrived. It also says to do some basic owners checks every 6 months, but that's stuff like refilling the washer fluid and making sure the parking brake works.

It then says that it will tell you when you've driven enough miles to warrant a service. Obviously I haven't driven anywhere near that amount of miles:

> **Intelligent Oil-Life Monitor®**
>
> This means you do not have to remember
>   to change the oil on a mileage-based
>   schedule.

I cannot find *any* reference to a time-based schedule for regular mechanical servicing. 12 months seems like a long time and I'm concerned I've missed the traditional "first" service of a new car.

When should I be getting this car serviced?

Comment: I like to do an oil change after a couple thousand miles on a new car. I'd do it regardless of what the computer says. Once a year at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @cory you should do an oil change once every 12 months or so regardless of how many miles are on the car. As the car has never been serviced since you bought it, even with those few miles, you are definitely due or an oil change, even if the on board computer doesn't think so.

Since you've had it for a year, you should probably have the first periodic maintenance done as well, depending on what's listed. Typically that interval is some number of miles or a year, whichever comes first. If nothing else, if you take it to the dealer where you bought it, they can certainly give you definitive advice about when that first service should be done. It's an important service since it's the first real look at the car since it left the factory. So having the dealer do it is a good idea.

If you're going to leave the car sitting for long periods with few miles on it, you may want to consider full synthetic oil, and driving it up and down the street a few times a month. This keeps parts at least somewhat lubricated, keeps the tires from flat spotting, etc. Sitting is not good for a car.

Answer (score 1):

This [Ford Motor Company video](http://owner.ford.com/how-tos/vehicle-features/dashboard-instrument-cluster/intelligent-oil-life-monitor.html?fmccmp=myfordmag-site-MFPR0515OIL) explains Intelligent Oil-Life Monitoring.

At the end of the video, it states that if it has been a year since your last oil change, regardless of the mileage, the system will remind you to get one.

So, either it has not been a full 365 days yet, or your system may be malfunctioning. If it has definitely been more than a year, have the system checked. Otherwise, it will not hurt to have the oil changed and the Intelligent Oil-Life Monitoring reset.

Comment: I don't know when the 365 days starts counting but I took delivery 11.5 months ago (just checked). So hopefully you're right.